# putExtra on dynamically created views android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a list of Strings. I am adding a RelativeLayout dynamically for each of them and adding TextViews dynamically in each of the relativelayouts. Now when I click, I am sending this textview value to the next activity. Below is the code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < Names.size(); i++)
    {                       
    textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(Names.get(i)); 

         rt=new RelativeLayout(this);
        rt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mednamedash);
        int curTextViewId = prevTextViewId + 1;
        int curRLId = prevRLId + 1;
        textView.setId(curTextViewId);
        rt.setId(curRLId);
        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, prevTextViewId);


        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvParams = 
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tvParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        rt.addView(textView, tvParams);


       prevTextViewId = curTextViewId;
        prevRLId=curRLId;
        noon.addView(rt, params);
        rt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(Dashboard.this,ReminderPopUp.class);
                i.putExtra("medicinename", textView.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
```

The problem is that if I have 10 RelativeLayouts with different texts and I am clicking on anyone of them, no matter which one I am clicking, only the last value of textview is passed to the next activity; not the value for which I clicked.
Please help
Thank you

Comment: Why aren't you sending Names.get(i) instead of sending textView.getText().toString()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting always the last one because you are  overriding the member class at every iteration of the loop.

you could set the `OnClickListener` to the `TextView` instead of the `RelativeLayout` and cast `v`, the clicked `View`, to `TextView`

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i=new Intent(Dashboard.this,ReminderPopUp.class);
            i.putExtra("medicinename", ((TextView)v).getText().toString());
            startActivity(i);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use the clicked view which is your textview for that change your code to this.By following so you will get the context of currently clicked textview not the last one.

```
rt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView txt=(TextView)v;
                Intent i=new Intent(Dashboard.this,ReminderPopUp.class);
                i.putExtra("medicinename", txt.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In onClick, get the text view from the relative layout as

```
 TextView textView = (TextView) rl.getChildAt(0);
 String name= textView.getText().toString();
```